# Magento 2.4.1: templatehints=magento doesn't seem to work on the payment method page

Tags: magento2.4.1

templatehints=magento displays the templates for other pages on the storefront than the payment method page. When entered the parameter on this page, it redirects to 404 page. Any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: The payment methods are generated using knockoutJS so path hints will not working on this section of the website. my suggestion would be to find the module in the vendor folder and copy the files needed to your theme and once you have done so you can edit them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gordon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:
http://yourdomain.com/checkout/?templatehints=magento#payment
if it work you can accept to help other.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working.